# Why does my Windows 7 VM running under Linux' KVM not use all the virtual processors?

Tags: windows-7, multi-core, kvm-virtualization

All

I've had a problem on my server since I migrated one of my VM's from Windows 2008 Server to Windows 7 (ultimate): though I've assigned four cores to the VM and it even seems to see them, it seems to think it has two cores!

[image: It recognises my processors but doesn't use them!]

Can anyone tell me what's going on here?  I thought it could have been some incompatibility between KVM and Windows 7 but since it sees the virtual processors I'm beginning to think not...any clues?

Here's a screenshot of process manager showing only two cores on the same box:

[image: Task manager]

Comment: Are you sure that it's not showing you two dual-core procs?

Comment: @phoebus: I did wonder that, but then on all versions of windows where I have run this setup before I see four cores when looking in processor monitor, which I don't here.

Comment: When you say processor monitor, do you mean the performance monitoring section of task manager?  Because based solely on your screenshots, you're showing evidence of two, two-core processors.  If that's the case, you should see all 4 cores in the performance monitor.  If you don't, then yes, something is wonky.

Comment: @phoebus: yes, I mean the performance monitoring section of task manager.  Definitely seems wonky to me...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I suspect the processors are being presented as single core processors in separate sockets. Windows 7 ultimate supports up to 2 socket systems, so it will use 2 processors.

I don't know if you can configure KVM to present the processors as either a single quad core CPU or 2 dual core CPUs, which should resolve the problem.

Comment: That's correct. ATM there's no way to change the topology.

Comment: Wow, I did't know this.  Thanks for correctly putting your finger on the issue.

@Luca: do you know if such support is planned?  I'm I actually using the extra two cores or are they going to waste?

Comment: @Luca: actually since qemu 0.12 you can change the topology.  I've upgraded my userspace kvm components but I think I need the new kernel mod for it to work....anyway, it can be done :)

Comment: Ah, cool... I should upgrade too then :)

Comment: Keep in mind that you can run the newest kvm kernel module on your current older kernel.  You will probably have to compile the module yourself unless you can find a repository for your distro that has the binary for you.  But building a module isn't too difficult to do.

Comment: This answer is old by now. See @Mark Dayel's answer for a how-to. By this time your kvm/libvirt/qemu should be recent enough to handle more than 2 CPUs just fine.

Comment: @LucaTettamanti That is [incorrect](https://s16.postimg.io/c9qjmzgdx/libvirt_topology.png) now (over five years later)

Comment: The same appears to be true for Windows 10. I changed the topology to 1 socket, 2 cores, and 2 threads per core and now it is able to use the full CPU.

Answer (score 26):

On libvirt 0.8.3, if you type:

```
virsh capabilities | grep topology
```

it will list the topology of the host:

```
<topology sockets='1' cores='4' threads='1'/>
```

The numbers refer to sockets, cores per socket, and threads per core.  Add this line to the cpu entry in the xml file to allow windows to use all 4 cores, e.g.:

```
 <vcpu>4</vcpu>
 <cpu>
     <topology sockets='1' cores='4' threads='1'/>
 </cpu>
```

Comment: knew it, but forgot about it - well then again there's serverfault and all those people writing all this awesome stuff. thanks for the tip!

Comment: I tried this on my RHEL 7.2 machine. Added `<topology sockets='1' cores='4' threads='1'/>` to my xml. `virsh capabilities | grep topology` shows `<topology sockets='1' cores='6' threads='2'/>`. CRITICAL: performed a `kill -HUP nnnnn` where nnnnn is the PID of my libvirtd process. Started the VM. It worked. +1 ! Thanks!  ...But don't forget to kick libvirtd with either a HUP signal or a restart!

Answer (score 5):

Topology settings are fully supported in virt-manager since Ubuntu 15.04.

From virt-manager > CPUs > Topology:

- Check: Manually set CPU topology
- Sockets: 2
- Cores: 2
- Threads: 2

The following is created from the above settings in virt-manager. You do not need to enter these with virsh edit.

```
<vcpu placement='static'>8</vcpu>
<cpu mode='host-model'>
  <model fallback='allow'/>
  <topology sockets='2' cores='2' threads='2'/>
</cpu>
```

Topology stopped being recognized by windows after an update, and again limits the Virtual CPU's to 2 sockets.

To fix this, use 'virsh edit' to hide the kvm feature, and add hyperv features. After a complete shutdown and reboot the windows VM will again recognize multiple CPU's.

[Why does my Windows 7 VM running under Linux' KVM not use all the virtual processors?](https://serverfault.com/questions/101434/why-does-my-windows-7-vm-running-under-linux-kvm-not-use-all-the-virtual-process)

```
<features>
  <acpi/>
  <apic/>
  <hyperv>
    <relaxed state='on'/>
    <vapic state='on'/>
    <spinlocks state='on' retries='8191'/>
  </hyperv>
  <kvm>
    <hidden state='on'/>
  </kvm>
</features>
```

Comment: This option was the only works for me! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In RHEL/CentOS 5.5 (kvm >= 83-164.el5) the kvm binary supports the "-smp N,cores=N" option too (there are backport patches in the package); however, the libvirt version does not support the <topology> element in the domain XML. A workaround is to create a wrapper script for /usr/libexec/kvm which adds the appropriate option and specify that script in the <emulator> element instead of the default path.

Answer (score 1):

It is worth noting that Ubuntu 10.4 (Lucid) has version 0.7.5 of libvirt while [support for topology](http://libvirt.org/news.html) was added to libvirt in version 0.7.6.  Ubuntu 10.10 (Maverick) has 0.8.3 libvirt and so should be able to directly support the topology specification in the XML without a wrapper.